# Copying a set of local files to FTP server

Tags: command-line, ftp, batch

I want to copy a set of local files to ftp://124.30.124.230 (it will ask username and password). I want to do this work on 400 systems.

I have planned to do this work by creating a batch file and while running this batch file, this has to do that work. How can I do it?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Batch files and plain FTP. So p[robably windows 98 era.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information regarding the systems you are running it on, the connections, any security, etc.

Personally, I think batch files are a great way of doing this. I've the contents of a simple backup one I'll happily share - you could tailor it to your FTP situation rather than the remote disk and folder creation I used.

[FTP batch script](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269))

My backup and upload script/bat file:

(Note this was for 2 [Windows XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP) PC's on a mini workgroup with a WAN connection (###.###.###.###) to a backup server, $$$$'s are my local usernames and it was run from the desktop.)

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:/" %%i in ("%DATE%") do set DATESTAMP=%%i.%%j.%%k
@echo Directory will be made with this name:
@echo backup.%DATESTAMP%
md backup.%DATESTAMP%
@echo Directory made, now proceeding with file copy...
@echo .
@echo please ensure both PC's are not in E-mail or have any documents open.
pause
cd backup.%DATESTAMP%
md "$$$$ Documents"
xcopy "c:\documents and settings\all users\documents\$$$$ documents" "$$$$ Documents" /E /C /I /H /Q
@echo in $$$$ Documents Complete.
pause
md "My Documents"
xcopy "c:\documents and settings\$$$$\my documents" "My Documents" /E /C /I /H /Q
@echo $$$$ My Documents Complete.
pause
md "$$$$ Email"
xcopy "c:\documents and settings\$$$$\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook" "$$$$ Email" /E /C /I /H /Q
@echo $$$$ Email Complete.
@echo .
@echo Now ready to upload to FTP backup server.
pause
ftp
open ###.###.###.###
backup
backup
put backup.%DATESTAMP%
quit
@echo upload to FTP backup complete!
pause
exit
```

Comment: Hi Haydn, I am using windows XP and it is a normal connection i.e., No firewall between the systems.. Please provide me the coding. I will test it out..

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use

```
ftp -s:myftpcommands.txt servername
```

On Unix/Linux you can use

```
ftp servername <myftpcommands.txt
```